# How can I get TTYs to work with NVIDIA drivers?

Tags: nvidia

If I'm debugging my graphics driver, I rely on the commandlines I can access by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1-F6. However, after installing the latest NVIDIA drivers, the screen goes black when I switch to those TTYs. How can I get the TTYs to work with the NVIDIA drivers?

I tried some of the proposals from other questions, like the "closed as too localized"  question here: [How do I get my blacked out ttys back?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43386/how-do-i-get-my-blacked-out-ttys-back) and the very involved suggestion here: [Can't view output in tty. (Ctrl+alt+f1 to f6 don't work, and display a black screen).](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276694/cant-view-output-in-tty-ctrlaltf1-to-f6-dont-work-and-display-a-black-scr)

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with all the latest updates. Here's some system information:

```
└─>lspci | grep -i vga
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 640M Mac Edition] (rev a1)

└─>lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
pci_stub               12622  1 
vboxpci                23194  0 
vboxnetadp             25670  0 
vboxnetflt             27613  0 
vboxdrv               409768  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
bnep                   19624  2 
rfcomm                 69160  12 
nls_iso8859_1          12713  1 
arc4                   12608  2 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     46254  1 
btusb                  32412  0 
bluetooth             391196  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
uvcvideo               80885  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         40664  1 uvcvideo
videodev              134688  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
b43                   387371  0 
snd_hda_codec_cirrus    18855  1 
mac80211              630653  1 b43
cfg80211              484040  2 b43,mac80211
ssb                    62379  1 b43
snd_hda_intel          52355  5 
snd_hda_codec         192906  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_cirrus
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102099  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
intel_rapl             18773  0 
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    14205  0 
intel_powerclamp       14705  0 
coretemp               13435  0 
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
kvm_intel             143060  0 
snd_timer              29482  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
kvm                   451511  1 kvm_intel
crct10dif_pclmul       14289  0 
crc32_pclmul           13113  0 
snd                    69238  21 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_cirrus,snd_seq_midi
ghash_clmulni_intel    13216  0 
applesmc               19308  0 
input_polldev          13896  1 applesmc
aesni_intel            55624  0 
aes_x86_64             17131  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    13286  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               14951  1 lrw
glue_helper            13990  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            13597  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20359  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
parport_pc             32701  0 
ppdev                  17671  0 
lpc_ich                21080  0 
lp                     17759  0 
bcma                   52096  1 b43
parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
nvidia              10527448  31 
soundcore              12680  1 snd
drm                   303102  2 nvidia
video                  19476  0 
mac_hid                13205  0 
apple_bl               13993  0 
mei_me                 18627  0 
mei                    82276  1 mei_me
hid_apple              13386  0 
hid_generic            12548  0 
tg3                   166442  0 
sdhci_pci              23172  0 
sdhci                  43015  1 sdhci_pci
ptp                    18933  1 tg3
pps_core               19382  1 ptp
ahci                   25819  4 
usbhid                 52570  0 
libahci                32560  1 ahci
hid                   106148  3 hid_generic,usbhid,hid_apple
uvesafb                28686  0
```

Edit: I'm using the package `nvidia-340` from the `xorg-edgers` PPA:

```
└─>apt-cache policy nvidia-340
nvidia-340:
  Installed: 340.24-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.04.1
  Candidate: 340.24-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 340.24-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.04.1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I also tried disabling the framebuffer as described here: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=168108#p864284. Still no luck.

Edit: I'm now using the package `nvidia-343` from the xorg-edgers PPA:

```
└─>apt-cache policy nvidia-343
nvidia-343:
  Installed: 343.13-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.04.1
```

Still no luck.

Comment: I would start with adding `vga=773` to the kernel params during boot. Or disable KMS by adding `nomodeset`.

Comment: I tried those. No effect--the screen is still black.

Comment: Have you got webmin installed ? This shows you all the things that load at startup (amongst other things) and you can enable and disable the TTYs. (There are other ways to do this also but I find webmin real easy to use). Are they enabled ?

Comment: If you use a greeter instead of `startx`ing, it's kinda hard to debug since any modification might break things and you'd have to fix'em without seeing what you type. Try ALT+CTRL+F1, Ctrl+C a few times, wait a few seconds, and then, blindly, `sudo modprobe -r nvidia;sudo modprobe nvidia`.

Comment: @hatterman, it's not that TTYs aren't enabled, it's that the display is black when I switch to them.

Comment: @Alex, that didn't seem to have any effect. I also tried logging in blindly, entering those commands, then entering my sudo password, and that also didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: If the screen is black when pressing ctrl-alt F1 etc, then ttys are disabled, no ?

Comment: @hatterman, no, they definitely enabled, because typing commands blindly still works. They just aren't being displayed. This is apparently a common problem with NVIDIA drivers.

Comment: Thinking outside the box, have you tried this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/463306/change-color-of-command-line-text

Comment: Do you still have this problem?

Comment: Nvidia 340+ drivers have not worked for me on Ubuntu (14.10). I believe I'm using version 331. My card is a GTX 460 so it's a few years old but theoretically it should still be supported in the latest Nvidia drivers. Unfortunately I'm stuck using an old version indefinitely..

Comment: Also, I still get error messages every time I boot into my desktop. Not sure exactly what they're for but it's definitely Nvidia related. My machine is perfectly stable though, I have not had any issues with 331. If anyone else has this problem I would recommend downloading the .deb from Nvidia's official site.

Comment: @ElderGeek, I'm still having this problem.

Comment: @Jon Can you [edit] your question to give us an update of what you've tried in the way of offered solutions and suggestions and the results?

Comment: Have you looked at the rather expansive answer here? http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162535/why-does-switching-to-the-tty-give-me-a-blank-screen

Comment: @all + this looks to me after a missing matrix for display-situations ?! (would be necessary to scan the given ram-size for this) +

Answer (score 2):

First,

fix grub resolution:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Now, locate the line

```
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

and change it to this changing 1280x800 to the desired resolution:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x800 
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

Next,

add framebuffer (no, that's not a typo; use echo twice):

```
echo "echo FRAMEBUFFER=y" | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
```

finally, update grub and initramfs:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo update-grub
```

reboot for the changes to take effect

Comment: what's framebuffer? and what exactly does this echo line do?

Comment: @minamichael https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_framebuffer

Answer (score 0):

Did you try installing the Lastest Nvidia Drivers using this link ?

http://www.binarytides.com/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-14-04/

I have the lastest Nvidia and tty works fine on 14.04 64x.
P.S: Are you using the standard kde (Unity) ?

Comment: Yep. In the edit above I show which version (nvidia-340). I'm using neither KDE nor Unity, but that shouldn't matter, since TTYs should be before/behind any desktop environment anyway.

Comment: While this link may theoretically answer the question, please try to summarize the link in your post. Links sometimes go down. Also, "P.S." isn't really the proper form, especially for questions. Instead, comment on the original post.

Comment: @Whaaaaaat, just for the record, the above link doesn't answer the question. In the question, I explain how I use the guide from that link to install the `xorg-edgers` PPA, which provides the drivers I'm using which are causing this problem.

Comment: @Jon That's why I said *may*.

Answer (score 0):

First remove the xorg-edges drivers and pa from your system

Second go here: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/78469/en-us

Third download the drivery

Give

```
 chmod +x filename
```

Last but not least

```
./filename
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after updating packages/kernel last night and installing these helped my nVidia card gets detected again:

```
nvidia-331
nvidia-331-updates
nvidia-current
nvidia-current-updates
xserver-xorg-lts-raring
nvidia-prime
```

Of course you can replace 311 with other versions in repositories, but I think what fixed it is `xserver-xorg-lts-raring`

Then run

```
glxinfo | grep renderer
```

It should show your card (earlier it wasn't showing for me).

Answer (score 0):

have you also tried to download the driver for you specific device and run the installation through WINE? It's a possible route you could try. i have done the same when i ran ubuntu 13.10 and it wouldn't recognize my nVidia graphics card. i put the installation disk in and went to my computer and over the disk drive, right clicked 'run in wine.' then when the installation was done, i just adjusted ubuntu to the correct resolution and it worked for me. i just had to move the driver to C drive under drivers and restarted ubuntu. im not sure if this would work for all different devices, but it's worth a shot, if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using all the boot options?

nomodeset,
noapic
no1apic,

etc (the livecd provides the whole list, as does this link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions

When I had display problems I experimented with these until I found one that got me to a usable system. Then from there I was able to solve the problem and remove the boot option.

Answer (score 0):

open this with your text editor

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

edit this to your resolution:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

save and exit:

press ctrl+o to save

press ctrl+x to exit

update grub and reboot:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Could you expand on this answer? How does setting the initial GRUB Graphics mode to a specific resolution keep the terminals from showing up as a black screen?

Comment: its just something to try. i know my TTY is running in high resolution. something that "may" be happening is that the monitor itself may not be supporting a low resolution. so trying to set it to a higher resolution may fix the issue.

Comment: Good thought. We should find out what his monitor supports.

Comment: added a couple extra steps that i forgot to mention since its important to update grub and reboot or you wont see the resolution changes.